# Referencing list boxes in Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I'm new to Access so this might be a simple question.

I have a form in Access 2013. There is a subform displaying a table from an SQL server, like so.

```
Company   Product
-----------------
CompanyA  Product1
CompanyA  Product2
CompanyB  Product1
CompanyB  Product2
```

Using [ListIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193579.aspx) in a list box, I can display the index of any row I click on. For example if I click on the second row (CompanyA, Product2) the list box shows a ListIndex of 1. If I click on the third row the ListIndex is 2.

**How do I get a list box to display the value of a column instead of the ListIndex?**

What I am trying to do is that, when I click on a row in the subform, I'd like to display each column value for that row in its own list box.

[image: Screenshot]

However, I cannot seem to use ListIndex as a variable in a larger function. I've attempted the following:

- Typing only the column name into the list box. Does not update the value if I click on a different row.
- [Column property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192660.aspx) does not update the value if I click on a different row.
- [Controls property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845021.aspx) gives an error.
- [Value property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193552.aspx) displays the correct row but only works for the first column.
- Combo boxes circle back to the problem that I need to use ListIndex as a variable.

Is there a different property I should be using? Am I missing something in the properties I tried?

Comment: While your question is well formulated, I have real trouble understanding what you are trying to do. Can you add a screenshot of the form, and the code you currently have for the first listbox? (Assuming I got that part right :) )

Comment: @Andre Screenshot has been added. The subform is called `[List3]` and is structured exactly like the example table above. The first list box contains `=[List3].[ListIndex]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a little confusion with terminology. Your `List3` is a list box, not a subform.

The fields `Company` and `Product` look like text boxes, but if the first one has the control source `=[List3].[ListIndex]`, and shows a text and not a number, it seems to be a listbox with height = one line.

I suggest using **text boxes** for `Company` and `Product`, with these control sources:

```
=[List3]
```

for the bound column. Alternatively, for consistency: `=[List3].Column(0)`

```
=[List3].Column(1)
```

for the second column.

These text boxes update themselves automatically when you click on an item in the listbox.

Comment: It works, thank you! It seems I didn't need `[ListIndex]` as a row argument in the Column property.

Comment: As a follow up question, how do I allow a user to also edit the value in the list box, and have the value update in the SQL server table?

Comment: @jjjjjjjjjjj: list boxes are not for editing their values, they are for selecting a value. You'll need a separate form (or simply the datasheet) for that.

Comment: Good to know, thanks. For people who find this thread, I accomplished this with one form. In the form design view, I edited the referenced fields as shown by Andre, and left the fields to edit as their default values (the column name). After editing a field, you'll need to hit CTRL+S to commit the changes to the SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of a listbox, and if you allow multi-select, use the following example:

```
    For Each varItem In Me.lstHierarchy.ItemsSelected           ' Loop through the items selected (if multi-select allowed)
        strPrint = ""
        For i = 0 To iCols                                      ' Loop thru each column in a row
            strPrint = strPrint & "|" & Me.lstHierarchy.Column(i, varItem)
        Next i
        Debug.Print "Selected Value: " & strPrint               ' Display the row; columns are delimited with '|'
    Next
```

Comment: My original understanding of what you wrote is that your listbox currently shows values (CompanyA, Product1); I assumed since you were using the 'ListIndex' property, you probably were doing that with VBA code. But now that you have clarified the problem, you can disregard my answer. I was showing you how to get the values selected in a listbox using VBA code... which you could have done in the 'Click' event for your listbox.